# Como armazenar imagens num vetor Android?

Tags: java, android

Tenho imagens dentro da `drawable` e para acessa-la basta `R.drawable.myimage`.
Como armazenar essa imagens num `vetor`?

Comment: Já tentou armazenar apenas a referencia delas?

Comment: Qual é o seu intuito?

Comment: @ramaral é o seguinte para poder passar por parâmetro, exemplo `image[0], image[1]....` mudando os números com um incrementador

Comment: @ramaral ou utilizando String para acessa-las

Comment: @DiegoF não como seria?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não guarde as imagens, guarde os seus *resource Id* usando um `int[]`:

```
int[] imagensIds = {
    R.drawable.image1,
    R.drawable.image2,
    R.drawable.image3
};
```

Você pode passar todas as imagens para um método:

```
processaImagens(imagensIds);
```

ou apenas uma:

```
processaImagem(imagensIds[1]);
```

Declare o métodos da seguinte forma:

```
private processaImagens(int[] imagensIds){
}

private processaImagem(int imagemId){
}
```

Comment: +1 Acredito que essa é a melhor forma.

Comment: @DiegoF Eu ainda esperei que você respondesse.

Comment: Pra falar a verdade eu não tinha nem chegado a pensar em algo pra responder, a sugestão foi meio que automática quando vi a pergunta. :/

Comment: @ramaral é possível colocar os  ` resource Id` num bloco notas ou seja `arquivo.txt` fazer ler esse arquivo e armazenar num vetor de inteiro? se sim como?

Comment: Sim é possível. Um `resource Id` não é mais do que um inteiro. Pode usar SharedPreferences para isso.

Comment: Como você sabe não devemos utilizar os comentários para fazer e responder novas perguntas:)

Comment: @ramaral beleza vou abri uma nova pergunta

Answer (score -2):

como esta resposta está muito tempo sem complemento vai ai:
///crio um Gallery
Gallery gallery1;

//declara um array de imagens já coladas no Drawable como pic0....:
Integer[] imagensID = {
R.drawable.pic0,
R.drawable.pic1,
R.drawable.pic2,
R.drawable.pic3
};
no onCreate eu inicio e faço a logica para pegar as imagens
//////////galeria de fotos, carroussel e tudo mais
Gallery gallery = (Gallery)findViewById(R.id.gallery);
gallery.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));
gallery.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

```
           //se chegar na ultima imagem, volta para a primeira
            if (position >=9){
                gallery.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(getApplicationContext()));
                return;
            }
        }
    });

    gallery.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
         return true;
        }
    });
    ///////fim da galeria de fotos
```

//ciro uma classe para configurar as imagens e tal
///inicio do image adapter, peguei em algum lugar e melhorei para o meu uso
///se lembrasse daria os créditos

public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
private Context context;
private int itemBackground;
public ImageAdapter(Context c){
context =c;
TypedArray a = obtainStyledAttributes(R.styleable.Gallery1);
itemBackground=a.getResourceId(R.styleable.Gallery1_android_galleryItemBackground, 0);
a.recycle();
}
@Override
public int getCount(){
return imagensID.length;
}
@Override
public Object getItem(int position){
return position;
}
@Override
public long getItemId(int position){
return position;
}
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);
imageView.setImageResource(imagensID[position]);

```
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
            imageView.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
            imageView.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(650, 600));
            imageView.setBackgroundResource(itemBackground);
            return imageView;
    }
```

//pega a imgem e seta na imageView com o tamnaho do setLayoutParams
public View getView1(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);
imageView.setImageResource(imagensID[position]);
imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
imageView.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(780, 1280));
imageView.setBackgroundResource(itemBackground);
return imageView;
}

}
///fim do image adapter